# PHP string errors

Tags: php, string, post

I am writing a program and have some code inside a string.  This code is error free outside a string, however, when I put it inside a string, I get this error.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in ****directory and line number****

The errors occur on

```
$string = "if(isset($_POST['Submit']))";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why downvoting? Seems quite a legitimate question to me...

Comment: can you please explain what actually you want to do with your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single quotes, and not double quotes:

```
$string = 'if(isset($_POST[\'Submit\']))';
```

this way, PHP will not try to interpolate the $_POST variable inside it. Otherwise, escape the $ character.

Comment: They would also have to escape the quotes inside the string.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape `$`:

```
$string = "if(isset(\$_POST['Submit']))";
```

Answer (score 0):

[lloyd@desktop ~]$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $string = "if(isset($_POST['Submit']))";
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in php shell code on line 1

php > $string = "if(isset(\$_POST['Submit']))";

php > $string = "if(isset({$_POST['Submit']}))";

PHP Notice:  Undefined index: Submit in php shell code on line 1
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() php shell code:0

php >

You need to escape the $ as PHP is trying to parse the string, as it is in double quotes. If you want that exact string without PHP trying to interpret then use single quotes.